# Cant access object passed to component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

[image]

I want to pass an object to a React component. This object is the state of the parent element, which updates dynamically with updates from firebase. However, when I pass this object to the component and try accessing its value, I am getting undefined.

When I try to log this object in console, it show the key value pair with `Value below was just evaluated now`. How do I access the attributes of this object ?

State of the parent

```
state = {
    isSignedIn: false,
    userVal: {},
    cards: {},
    coin: 0,
    room_id: 0
  };
```

Object getting updated

```
db.collection("users").doc(this.state.userVal.uid).onSnapshot(query => {
        let q = query.data();
        this.setState({ room_id: q.room_id, coin: q.coins });
        for (const key in q) {
          if (key !== "room_id" && key !== "name" && key !== "coins" && key !== "email" && key !== "no") {
            let temp = this.state.cards;
            temp[key] = q[key];
            this.setState({ cards: temp });
          }
        }
      })
```

Object passed to the component

```
<Cards id={this.state.userVal.uid} room_id={this.state.room_id} cards={this.state.cards} />
```

`this.state.cards` is the problematic one

Comment: It will be useful if you show us some of your code.

Comment: it's probably because getting firebase is async function.

Comment: do not use set State in Loop first of all not a good approach

Comment: Accept the answer if it works.

Comment: @BillF, probably you are right

Answer (score 1):

It's because the scope for this is undefined. You need to pass it through with ES6 arrow functions.

```
  db.collection("users").doc(this.state.userVal.uid).onSnapshot(query => {
    let q = query.data();
    this.setState({ room_id: q.room_id, coin: q.coins });
    q.forEach((key) => {
      if (key !== "room_id" && key !== "name" && key !== "coins" && key !== "email" && key !== "no") {
        let temp = this.state.cards;
        temp[key] = q[key];
        this.setState({ cards: temp });
      }
    })
  })
```

Try it this way.

Comment: I have found a workaround which doesnt involve sending objects to the components. However this doesnt work